# A recipient must be specified error when sending email from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

We are trying to send the out the output of a html string to a particular test email address and found this error at runtime:

```
A recipient must be specified.
```

Here is the coding from the code-behind file.

```
Protected Sub EmailTheList()

    ' Get the rendered HTML.
    '-----------------------
    Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
    Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)
    Dim htmlTW As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)

    GridViewSummary.RenderControl(htmlTW)

    ' Get the HTML into a string.
    ' This will be used in the body of the email report.
    '---------------------------------------------------
    Dim dataGridHTML As String = SB.ToString()

    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myEmailAddress@gmail.com", "myPassword")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True

    ObjMailMessage = New MailMessage()

    Try
        ObjMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("myEmailAddress@gmail.com", "Some text is here.", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        ObjMailMessage.Subject = "Test message from Emad"
        ObjMailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("john.doe@example.com")
        ObjMailMessage.Body = dataGridHTML

        ObjMailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure

        SmtpServer.Send(ObjMailMessage)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

We suspect we are not using the correct syntax for this line:

```
ObjMailMessage.From = ObjMailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("john.doe@example.com")
```

Comment: This is a weird error, as I had set the bcc list. I guess only the "To" is considered as canonical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the To: address, which is causing the error regarding a recipient.

```
ObjMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("mail@somemail.com", "An error happened", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply. I tried ObjMailMessage.To = New MailAddress("mail@somemail.com", "An error happened", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) but got an error that: Property 'To' is 'ReadOnly'

Comment: Sorry, the To: property is a collection.  I updated the answer- you should be able to Add a new MailAddress to the collection.